# Alterar a Fonte de um ListView que foi criado em Fragment

Tags: c#, xamarin, xaml

Onde eu altero o tipo de fonte e cor no controle ListView?

Os controles ListView estão no main.xaml como abaixo:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#818181"
    android:foreground="#E2E2E2"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_e_cardapio" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#E2E2E2"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:foreground="#E2E2E2"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_d_cardapio" />
```

No MainActivity está o código que cria a lista do ListView.

```
mLeftDataSet = new List<string>();
mLeftDataSet.Add ("Cadastros");
mLeftDataSet.Add ("Consultas");
mLeftDataSet.Add("Relatorios");
mLeftDataSet.Add("Tarefas");
mLeftAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, mLeftDataSet);
mLeftDrawer.Adapter = mLeftAdapter;

mRightDataSet = new List<string>();
mRightDataSet.Add ("Sobre");
mRightDataSet.Add ("Versão");
mRightDataSet.Add("Ajuda");
mRightAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, mRightDataSet);
mRightDrawer.Adapter = mRightAdapter;
```